# Partial string matching mysql

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching, string-matching

I'm working with Bank Transaction data of customers and I'm looking to exclude the transactions which contain part or the entirety of the customer names.
My data looks like this:

```
Table A:
Cust_ID       |TxnDescription                       |
-----------   |-------------------------------------|
C123-------   |#######LIANDRI CORPORATION###########|
C123-------   |#########LIANDRI#####################|
C123-------   |############JEFF L###################|
C123-------   |#########K.S. LI ANDRI###############|
C123-------   |############XAN KRIEGOR##############|
C123-------   |####AXON RESEARCH CORPORATION########|
C123-------   |############FENTECH INCORPORATED#####|
C123-------   |########PHAYDER CORPORATION##########|
C123-------   |############IZANAGI CORPORATION######|

Table B:
Cust_ID       |PromoterName                         |
--------------|-------------------------------------|
C123          |LIANDRI CORPORATION                  |
C123          |JEFF LIANDRI                         |
C123          |K S LIANDRI                          |
C123          |XAN KRIEGOR                          |
C324          |IZANAGI CORPORATION                  |
```

My desired output is:

```
TABLE: E
Cust_ID       |TxnDescription                       |Fl_Exclude  |
-----------   |-------------------------------------|------------|
C123-------   |#######LIANDRI CORPORATION###########|YES         |
C123-------   |#########LIANDRI#####################|YES         |
C123-------   |############JEFF LI ANDRI############|YES         |
C123-------   |#########K.S. LI ANDRI###############|YES         |
C123-------   |############XAN KRIEGOR##############|YES         |
C123-------   |####AXON RESEARCH CORPORATION########|NO          |
C123-------   |############FENTECH INCORPORATED#####|NO          |
C123-------   |########PHAYDER CORPORATION##########|NO          |
C123-------   |############IZANAGI CORPORATION######|NO          |
```

My approach here is to break promoter names in table B into Words as shown below:

```
TABLE: C
Cust_ID       |PromoterNamePart                     |
--------------|-------------------------------------|
C123          |LIANDRI                              |
C123          |CORPORATION                          |
C123          |JEFF                                 |
C123          |LIANDRI                              |
C123          |K S                                  |
C123          |LIANDRI                              |
C123          |XAN                                  |
C123          |KRIEGOR                              |
```

And then remove duplicates to take care of ambiguity

```
TABLE: D
Cust_ID       |PromoterNamePart                     |
--------------|-------------------------------------|
C123          |LIANDRI                              |
C123          |JEFF                                 |
C123          |K S                                  |
C123          |XAN                                  |
C123          |KRIEGOR                              |
```

Upon joining **A** and **D** on **Cust_ID** and a **like** clause using **D.PromoterNamePart** on **A.TxnDescription**, I'm expecting to get my output.

Now, I'm stuck at breaking table B in to C because single letter consecutive abbreviations are to be treated as a single word.

Any thoughts on how to approach this problem or any alternate solutions would be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For breaking table b in c you need somethings for split  .. this is not present in native mysql function ..But  you can build your (spilt)  function in two way (at least)

1. using a stored procedure
2. server side .. selecting from b and popoluate C proper using split or explode function (depend by your serverside env)

then Once you have table C

could be you can use like

```
select distinct 
    a.Cust_id
  , a.PromoterNamePart
  , case when a.PromoterNamePart like concat('%',d.PromoterNamePart, '%') 
                  Then 'YES'
                   ELSE 'NO' 
          END as Fl_Exclude
from tableA as a
left join tableD as d
```